# Growth estimate of $1/\Gamma$: majorizing $ce^{(|s|+1)\log(|s|+1)}e^{\pi|s|}$ by $c_1 e^{c_2 |s| \log |s|}$ where $c_1,c_2$ are independent of $s$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

I am reading the following growth estimate of the reciprocal of the gamma function from Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis.

[image]

In this proposition, the bounding constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ seem to be independent of $s$. However, from the proof, I am not sure how to get such bounds. Firstly, how do we get that for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a bound $c(\epsilon)$ so that $|1/\Gamma(s)| \le c(\epsilon) e^{c_2 |s|^{1+\epsilon}}$ from the bound $c_1 e^{c_2}|s|\log |s|$?

Next is the proof of the proposition. Here $\sigma=Re(s)$, and they bound the second term by $ce^{(|s|+1)\log(|s|+1)}e^{\pi |s|}$. And say this itself is majorized by $c_1 e^{c_2 |s| \log |s|}$. But I cannot figure out how to get the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ independent of $s$.

[image]

Finally they deal with the first term as follows. In this case, they get a bound $ce^{\pi |s|}$. But we need a bound of the form $c_1 e^{c_2 |s| \log |s|}$. Again, how do we bound $ce^{\pi |s|}$ by $c_1 e^{c_2 |s| \log |s|}$ independent of $s$?

[image]

I would greatly appreciate some help in establishing these bounds.

Comment: The constant $c(\epsilon)$ is obtained from the fact that for all $p>0$ there is $C_p\geq 1$ with $\log(s)\leq C_ps^p$ for all $s$.  As for the proof of (ii), it all seems straightforward to me. Can you please be more specific about what steps you don't follow?

Comment: @BenW From the estimate you gave, we have $c_1 e^{c_2 |s| \log |s|} \le c_1 e^{c_p c_2 |s|^{1+p}}$. But we need $c_p e^{c_2 |s|^{1+p}}$. How do we get the $c_p$ out of the exponent?

Comment: @BenW For the next steps my questions are: With what constants $c_1,c_2$ independent of $s$, (i) we get $ce^{(|s|+1)\log(|s|+1)}e^{\pi |s|} \le c_1 e^{c_2 |s| \log |s|}$? And (ii) we get $ce^{\pi |s|} \le c_1 e^{c_2 |s| \log |s|}$? The difficult part is that we need $c_1$ and $c_2$ to hold uniformly over all $s \in \mathbb{C}$, and I can't find out how.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician ,just a comment: cool username! Inspired by Cauchar Birkar? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\varepsilon>0$, the function $x \mapsto x\log x - x^{1 + \varepsilon }$ will eventually tend to $-\infty$ because the $\log$ eventually grows slower than any positive power. Also, it tends to $0$ as $x\to0+$. Hence, there is a $k(\varepsilon)>0$, such that $x \mapsto x\log x - x^{1 + \varepsilon } <k(\varepsilon)$ for all $x>0$.
Consequently
$$
c_1 e^{c_2 \left| s \right|\log \left| s \right|}  \le (c_1 e^{c_2 k(\varepsilon)}) e^{c_2\left| s \right|^{1 + \varepsilon } } .
$$
For your second question, note that
$$
(\left| s \right| + 1)\log (\left| s \right| + 1) + \pi \left| s \right| < (5\left| s \right|\log \left| s \right|) + 5
$$
for $|s|>0$. Thus,
$$
ce^{(\left| s \right| + 1)\log (\left| s \right| + 1)} e^{\pi \left| s \right|}  < (ce^5 )e^{5\left| s \right|\log \left| s \right|} .
$$
From this, it is also obvious that
$$
ce^{\pi \left| s \right|}  < (ce^5 )e^{5\left| s \right|\log \left| s \right|} .
$$

Comment: For the first question, how do we get $\epsilon$ out of the exponent? Because the proposition is gives the constants of the form $c(\epsilon) e^{c_2 |s|^{1+\epsilon}}$. So the constant $c_2$ in the exponent remains the same. And for the second question, could you explain how we get $(|s|+1) \log(|s|+1) + \pi |s| < 5(|s| \log |s| + 1)$?

Comment: Plot $(0, + \infty ) \ni x \mapsto \frac{{(x + 1)\log (x + 1) + \pi x}}{{(5x\log x) + 5}}$, and you can see that it is less than $1$.

Comment: Okay could you explain how you found this particular bound?

Comment: Experience. You have a sense about the growth rate of certain functions and know what kind of estimates you can expect. I knew that $(x+1)\log(x+1)+\pi x$ should be bounded if I divide it by $x\log x+1$ (their ratio tends to $1$ at infinity and is finite for all $x\geq 0$). I plotted the ratio and saw that it was always below $5$.